# Does the themostat have anything with the A/C working then not working

Tags: ac

Does the thermostat have anything to do with the A/C working then not working? I was told it did, but it makes no sense to me. When the temperature gauge works, the A/C does, when it does not the A/C does not?

Comment: In terms of function no, but they could be supplied from the same circuit or fuse...

Comment: Welcome to the site ... is there anyway you could clarify your question? As it's written, it's very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the thermostat allows the passage of water to the radiator when the water in the motor hits the maximum temperature of the thermostat. Then, let flow the hot water through the radiator and the cold water will flow back to the motor.

When you turn on the A/C, the motor works a little bit harder, that means that the temperature is going to increase, doing the cycle of the thermostat shorter.

**EDIT**
Does not have to do with the A/C in the way that you explain.